# EA plugin gives Please ensure this is not a forgotten debug statement

Tags: php, phpstorm

Since yesterday, I am getting this annoying message in `phpStorm`.

I am trying to do a simple `dd('variable-name');`

But I am getting `[EA] Please ensure this is not a forgotten debug statement.` marked with a red line.

Even though, it is working but that `red-line` is annoying to me.

Do i need to make some adjustment in this EA plugin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an inspection from **Php Inspections (EA Extended) plugin**. Such code should not be present in production code hence the very visible Error severity (so it's in your face, so you do not accidentally forget about it).

There are few options on what you can do here:

- Disable whole inspection if it annoys you
- Change the severity (from "Error" to something less noticeable, e.g. "Warning")
- Or you can remove just `dd()` function from that list and leave the rest in tact.

You can access that inspection straight from the code: <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while caret is on the error place (or via the Light Bulb icon) and use submenu to get there:

[image]

Or just go full way via Settings/Preferences:

- Settings/Preferences
- Editor | Inspections
- PHP | Php Inspections (EA Extended) | Probable bugs
- `Forgotten debug statements` inspection.

[image]

**HINT:** The search field on the top left will help you a lot to narrow it down:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also annotate it with a comment beforehand to suppress:

```
/** @noinspection ForgottenDebugOutputInspection */
```

Comment: This led me to the correct solution https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections